# Import JSON file as table in Excel and visualize polygon geometry using ArcGIS plugin for Excel

Tags: polygon, import, excel, json, arcgis-for-excel

I have a quest where I have to visualize the polygons in my local disk in Excel using ArcGIS plugin. Based on what I understand, I can only import it as a JSON file from the get data panel, but the ArcGIS plugin still does not accept the file as a geometry. My only other way is to import it from ArcGIS Online, but I need it in Excel as I need to visualize maps as I change certain attributes in real time.

What I have done so far:

1. Converted shapefile to .json file.
2. Converted it into table using get data panel.
3. Tried import the geometry column as location type in ArcGIS plugin.
   Error is "selected column doesnt contain any valid json geometry"
   [image: screenshot of error received]

Comment: Images of error messages are not legible in all devices and cannot be searched by others with the same error. Please [Edit] the Question to contain the actual error message as text.

Comment: What is the actual data in column H where it says `[List]`?

Comment: @til_b. When I import a json vector layer it took the geometry with coordinates as a column. So its a list of coordinates basically which make up the polygon. I dont know if its the right way to import the json file as column to get geometry either.

Answer (score 0):

When you only need to change attributes and not the geometry you can probably import the shapefiles once into ArcGIS, they need only an ID field and the geometry. Then you add the ID field to your Excel file, add the Excel file as a layer to ArcGIS and join both on the ID field.

General info on Excel in ArcGIS Pro is here https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/excel/work-with-excel-in-arcgis-pro.htm

Comment: Actually im comfortable with doing this with any geospatial software. The problem is my client is not and wants to open excel paste the new values for a given attribute and see changes in the map. So i want a template in excel where they can do this. Problem is with importing the polygons